# ElasticSearch install on AWS - unable to connect on public ip/host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, elasticsearch

I have an single EC2 CentOS instance with ElasticSearch installed.

I am unable to connect externally using the public ip or hostname.

ElasticSearch starts correctly and I can access locally on the machine using:

```
CURL <my_internal_ip>:9200
```

However running the same remotely using the public ip fails.

- I have the the cloud-aws plugin is installed
- I have setup an AWS security group with all tcp ports open for testing

I am guessing I need to bind the address within the elasticsearch.yml file, however do not understand which setting to use, and with what address. Setting the network.host to an external address stops ES from starting - unable to bind.

Appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours....

IP Tables was enabled on the OS as default blocking my elasticsearch ports.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Ec2 Instance is use remotely according with the Elastic Search Installed that provide the aws cloud plugins

Comment: Im not sure I understand your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: Amazon Ec2 instance use according for elastic search installation

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue and followed below steps and get resolved: 
[Elasticsearch process memory locking failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008355/elasticsearch-process-memory-locking-failed)

```
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

Do these two steps also.