# How to change Elasticsearch network host

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7

I've install ES on my VM which it has an OS of `centos 7`. It network.host: bind to the localhost. I can browse via port 9200.

My problem is that I've changed the network host to:`0.0.0.0` (So I can get public access from my host PC).
the service started but the port is not listening.

I want to access ES from my host PC.
How can i change the network.host ?

Comment: Use netstat -ntlp to check open ports. Check the ES logs

Comment: Take a loot at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449342/installed-elastic-search-on-server-but-cannot-connect-to-it-if-from-another-mach/34461159?noredirect=1#comment77157976_34461159.

Comment: @ManishR
I've tried but that won't success. Port is not listening for this, network.bind_host: 0 http.cors.allow-origin: "*" http.cors.enabled: true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Elasticsearch [Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings) documentation, it doesn't appear that `0.0.0.0` is a valid setting for `network.host`.

Try instead the [special value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values) `_global_`. So the section of your `elasticsearch.yaml` might look like this:

```
network:
  host: _global_
```

This should tell Elasticsearch to listen on *all* network interfaces.

Comment: I've changed then service failed to start. Again changed to localhost then works fine. What i want to do is sent logs to ES using Logstash installed on another server. ES ruining on another server.

Comment: Issue resolved after following below instructions. After IP change Memory lock not working on ES. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008355/elasticsearch-process-memory-locking-failed

Answer (score 32):

I faced same issue in elasticsearch 7.3.0 version. I resolved by putting following

values in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml as shown below

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Windows users you may find the config doesn't updates don't work. I discovered an environment variable in ES_CONFIG which pointed to application data. Updating that config file with these details worked.

Answer (score 6):

If you are planning to set `network.host` other than default(127.0.0.1) then change following details in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

- network.host: 0.0.0.0
- discovery.seed_hosts: []

Comment: I tried a bunch of different ways from Internet to force Elastic listen on 0.0.0.0 and only this one helped me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Same here, wasn't working without the discover.seed_hosts line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the version 7.3 of Elastic Search, it's necessary to put the following line

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: node-1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is running on AWS and Elastic search is running on different host

network.host: YOUR_AWS_PRIVATE_IP

This works for me.